# JS: How to use convert string to date and then use every method to check false input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, conditional-statements

Picture input form where user submits  from 1 up to 4 dates within same month. I have set like this:

//hardcoeding rage dates from March 6 to March 9.

```js
app.controller...
 $scope.rangeValidator = {
    startDate: '06/03/2017',
    endDate: '09/03/2017'
  }
```

---

```js
//Setting calendar available start and end date.

$scope.initCalendar = function() {
    $('#reclamoFecha .input-group.date').datepicker({
        multidate: true,
        multidateSeparator: ",",
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startDate: $scope.rangeValidator.startDate,
        endDate: $scope.rangeValidator.endDate,
        language: "es"
      });
  };
```

---

I want to check if ONLY inputs of dates in this range are submitted, and if false, an alert is executed. When user datepicker input it is logged as a String, also when many dates are submitted each date becomes part of the logged string, so I had to split into an array.

```js
// returns: "06/03/2017,07/03/2017,08/03/2017,09/03/2017"

$scope.validRangeDate = $rootScope.reclamo.fechas.split(',');

$scope.validateForm(function() {
     $scope.validRangeDate = $rootScope.reclamo.fechas.split(',');
     console.log($scope.validRangeDate);

//returns: ['06/03/2017','07/03/2017','08/03/2017','09/03/2017',]
```

so what I need to do is a conditional where I can check the if eg: 20/03/2017 is submited it triggers an alert.

I was thinking about setting a range between startdate and enddate with "every" method for the array.
I´m not quite sure if I should convert the string to Date before. Also not quite sure how to use that method on a function.

Comment: I already have the form. I need to access the returned array to validate if a new date input is out of range.
 Can I use Try Catch within a foreach loop to test if condition on each array element is met and then execute something?

Answer (score 0):

To check a date in a range you could create a custom validation method like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function(value, element, params) {
  try {
    var date = new Date(value);
    if (date >= params.from && date <= params.to) {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  return false;
}, 'Date out of range');
```

Then add the relative [class rules](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) in order to pass the two parameters for the valid range:

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
  myDateFieldRangeValidate: {
    dateRange: {
      from: fromDate,
      to: toDate
    }
  }
});
```

Finally add the validator to your field / fields:

```
$("#myField").addClass("myDateFieldRangeValidate");
```

See following complete example:

```js
var fromDate = new Date("2017-03-01");
var toDate = new Date("2017-03-31");

$.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function(value, element, params) {
  try {
    var date = new Date(value);
    if (date >= params.from && date <= params.to) {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  return false;
}, 'Date out of range');

$.validator.addClassRules({
  myDateFieldRangeValidate: {
    dateRange: {
      from: fromDate,
      to: toDate
    }
  }
});

$("#myField").addClass("myDateFieldRangeValidate");
$("#frm1").validate();
$("#btnValidate").click(function() {
  console.log($("#frm1").valid())
});

jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#frm1').validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1">
  Date
  <input type="text" id="myField" value="16 Feb 2017">
  <input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Validate">
</form>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Thank you Alessandro. you are using Try Catch... why not use Every method on the response array to get a false if ocndition is not met?

Comment: Yes, you could, I don't really understand what you have to do exactly... anyway you could search the date in the array instead to do this check: `if (date >= params.from && date <= params.to)`